# Connection error with mysql and servlet based project

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I am currently undertaking a course project where I am developing a recipe website using HTML, JSP, and Servlet. To streamline the retrieval of recipe data, I am attempting to establish a connection between my JSP code and the MySQL database. Unfortunately, despite my efforts, the connection is not functioning as expected.

I have thoroughly reviewed my code and implemented a try-catch statement in Java to handle potential issues. However, I am consistently encountering the error message 'Database connection error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.' I have attempted various troubleshooting approaches to identify the root cause, but I am unable to pinpoint the issue.

I am seeking guidance on resolving this connection error and understanding the specific steps or adjustments required to ensure a successful database connection. Any assistance or insights into overcoming this challenge would be greatly appreciated
Here is my code :

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page import="javax.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Recipe List</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    try {
        String loc=request.getParameter("location");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recipes_db","root","");

        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        String query="select * from recipes";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
%>

    <h2>Recipe List</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Recipe ID</th>
            <th>Recipe Name</th>
            <th>Ingredients</th>
            <th>Instructions</th>
        </tr>

        <%
            while (rs.next()) {
        %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= rs.getInt("recipe_id") %></td>
                    <td><%= rs.getString("recipe_name") %></td>
                    <td><%= rs.getString("ingredients") %></td>
                    <td><%= rs.getString("instructions") %></td>
                </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>

<%
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        out.println("Database connection error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
%>

</body>
```

Comment: See abovelinked duplicates for the assistance you was looking for.

Comment: The driver you are loading might be not available. Check out the driver path to find a suitable driver.